# Compare two records in two table in trigger sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want that if DELETED and INSERTED table have the same record then i will not update a another table. so please tell me how can i compare two rows in two different table DELETED and INSERTED having same structure.

please help me with sample code.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to test each and every column

```
INSERT OtherTable (keycol, col1, col2, ...)
SELECT
     I.keycol, I.Col1, I.Col2, ..
FROM
     INSERTED I
     JOIN
     DELETED D On I.keycol = D.keycol
WHERE
     I.col1 <> I.col1
     OR
     I.col2 <> I.col2
     OR
     ISNULL(I.col3, 0) <> ISNULL(I.col3, 0) --nullable columns
     OR
     ...
```

You can also use [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
INSERT ...
SELECT
     I.keycol, I.Col1, I.Col2, ..
FROM
     INSERTED I
     JOIN
     DELETED D On I.keycol = D.keycol
WHERE
     HashBytes('SHA1', CAST(I.col1 AS nvarchar) + I.col2 + etc)
     <>
     HashBytes('SHA1', CAST(D.col1 AS nvarchar) + D.col2 + etc)
```

Not 100% reliable, use [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
INSERT ...
SELECT
     I.keycol, I.Col1, I.Col2, ..
FROM
     INSERTED I
     JOIN
     DELETED D On I.keycol = D.keycol
WHERE
     CHECKSUM(I.*) <> CHECKSUM(D.*)
```